# How to show Math formulas on a website?

Tags: fonts

I am reading (in Chrome or Firefox) Math blogs, like [the n-Category Café](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/), but finding it difficult because Android will not show the Mathematical symbols (like integral signs, sums, arrows... etc).

Is there something I can do to fix that?

Comment: The website uses [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to show math formulas, and it's using JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried opening "n-category cafe" using Chrome in my Nexus 5, and it works normally.
So it's probably just a problem with your browser settings.
Check if you are allowing sites to run **Javascript** by going to **Settings -> Site Settings -> Javascipt** in your Chrome browser.